# Find duplicate rows in a matrix and add up one column for the duplicate rows

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, duplicates

I am working on a matrix where the first 7 columns consist of +1/-1's only, and the 8th column consists of positive decimal numbers. I want to find the duplicate rows (e.g. say there are two rows in the matrix such that
[-1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 1 0.32]
... (other distinct rows)
[-1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 1 0.1]
... (other distinct rows)
[-1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 1 0.005])
and then perform something similar to `count` in `plyr` in the sense that I keep only the unique rows but also add up the values in the 8th column. So in the example above, I would like to eventually have only 1 row where the first 7 entries are (-1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 1) and I have the 8th entry being 0.425.

I am not aware of such function in R and I do not know much about `plyr` / `dplyr`. I wonder whether there is an elegant solution other than me manually writing a loop iterating all possible (128) combinations of +1/-1 in a 7-element vector.

As suggested, I'm adding a reproducible example below. The dimension changes for simplicity.

```
dat = matrix(c(-1, -1, 1, 0.1, -1, -1, 1, 0.2, -1, -1, -1, 0.05, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, -1, -1, -1, .9999), nrow = 5, byrow = T)
```

I hope to get a matrix looking like this:
Screenshot of the desired output

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this would be to convert the matrix into dataframe and then use `aggregate`

```
temp <- data.frame(dat)
aggregate(temp$X4, temp[1:3], sum)

#  X1 X2 X3    x
#1 -1 -1 -1 1.05
#2 -1 -1  1 0.30
#3  1  1  1 0.50
```

In `dplyr`, we can use `group_by_at` which can accept column positions

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(dat) %>% group_by_at(1:3) %>% summarise(sum = sum(X4))
```

If needed the dataframe can be converted to matrix again.